# Should C++ class inheritance (almost) always be public?

Tags: c++

Should I always add `public` keyword when inheriting a class? When doing this code:

```
class Derived : public Base {

}
```

I think this the right thing to do in 99% cases. Right?

Comment: really depends on what code you want to show from Base via Derived

Comment: That is correct. 99% of the cases, classes are derived using the `public` keyword.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks. I thought so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what model you are looking for.

From [Scott Myers - Effective C++ Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) (a recommended read, btw):

> `public` inheritance means "is-a". If you write that class `D` ("Derived") publicly inherits from `class B` ("Base"), you are telling C++ compilers (as well as human readers of your code) that every object of type `D` is also an object of type `B`, but *not vice versa*

And

> `private` inheritance means "is-implemented-in-terms-of"

Comment: That is Meyers' term, although "secretly-is-a" or "privately-is-a" is a more understandable description I think, since it certainly still *"is-a"*, and a class is also implemented *in terms of* **all of** their member variables.

Comment: Great thanks!!! bump to meet comment length requirement

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because this matches the inheritance behavior of other object oriented programming languages like C# or Java.

If you would use `private` instead of `public`, the properties and methods of the Base class are hidden. This means that the compiler would not allow you to call public methods of the Base class if you have a pointer of the Derived class.

Comment: Thanks. This answer explains everything perfectly.

Comment: @bodacydo It actually doesn't explain very much.